# I am in danger of being blocked from asking any more questions

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

[image: I am in danger!]

Finally a warning banner has been installed to tell users that they are going to be banned to ask questions. This is very good. It saved me for getting banned again.

The banner says:"*...edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity*". Which questions should I edit? Should I edit my deleted questions Or my present undeleted questions? Or should I improve all of my questions?

What do we mean my *"well received"*? Do questions  to whom I haven't accepted an answer are called "*not well recieved*" or only which are downvoted? Or which are closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, this warning has been around for a while it seems.

"Not well received" means downvoted, closed, or deleted, with different weightages for the three.

Undelete your deleted questions if you self deleted them, and fix them. Also, fix your downvoted ones, take feedback from the people in chat.

The [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) in that banner lists how you can improve your questions and avoid a ban.

Comment: What should I do about those which are deleted by the community moderator?

Comment: @user31782 If you're able to edit them, feel free to do so and flag for undeletion. Otherwise, you can't do anything about them.